# Tag Question — Does it sometimes border upon a comma splice?

Tags: punctuation, question-tags

Tag Question — Does it sometimes border upon a comma splice?

I think it looks nice, *do* you? (This is a comma splice, correct?)

Shouldn't we technically use a period after "nice" in this sentence to avoid the splice?

Correct would be:

*I think it looks nice. Do you?*

But if we use *don't* instead of *do* in the sentence above, then I would think that we've eliminated a potential comma splice. (See below.)

I think it looks nice, *don't* you?

Comment: This is not a usual tag question, which repeats the subject pronoun: _I think it looks nice, don't I?_ This rarely happens with first person subjects. There are other kinds of tags, including the argumentative, which only occurs with two affirmatives: _You think it looks nice, do you?_ With a clause as short as _I think it looks nice_ there's really no room for comma intonation. The whole sentence _I think it looks nice -- do you?_, with suitable stress on ***I, nice,*** and ***you,*** is pronounced as one unit.

Comment: I'll insert the em dash in similar constructions, then. *I think it looks nice – do you?* Or I'll just use a full stop: *I think it looks nice. Do you?*

Comment: I'd probably say _I think it looks nice. What do you think?_

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> This is not a usual tag question, which repeats the subject pronoun: *I think it looks nice, don't I?* This rarely happens with first person subjects. There are other kinds of tags, including the argumentative, which only occurs with two affirmatives: *You think it looks nice, do you?* With a clause as short as *I think it looks nice* there's really no room for comma intonation. The whole sentence *I think it looks nice -- do you?*, with suitable stress on **I**, **nice**, and **you**, is pronounced as one unit.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a semicolon. 
I think it looks nice; do you?